# Meteor iron-router IRLibLoader.load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to load an external JS script before loading a specific page in my Meteor app as shown below, yet I am always getting error:

```
 Error: Exception in callback of async function:
ReferenceError: IRLibLoader is not defined
    at route.waitOn (http://localhost:3000/routes.js?e9b6488d58ebf0abefaf44c340c0603dacf1d069:27:13)
```

I am 100% sure iron-router is installed. Can someone tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
  this.route('dashboard', {
    path: '/dashboard',
    loginRequired: 'entrySignIn',
    onAfterAction: function() {
      SEO.set({
        title: 'My Meteor App | ' + SEO.settings.title
      });
    },
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            IRLibLoader.load('/assets/js/myscript.js')
        ]
    }    
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you added `manuelschoebel:wait-on-lib` package? or code snippet suggested at http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/use-meteor-iron-router-waiton-to-load-external-javascript

Comment: @Sasikanth Thanks a lot, I missed adding this package. One last question if you don't mind...I am trying to access the script which is placed in public folder under /public/assets/js/myscript.js but it doesn't seem to be loading it. Any thoughts what I might be missing in the path passed to the IRLibLoader load as shown in my question? Thanks again

Comment: path looks fine to me,anyway if it doesn't load try giving different paths and to make sure the script is added, write `console.log` somewhere in script and make sure it added.

Comment: @Sasikanth Just tried adding console.log('Test'); to my external script but nothing showed up, I've also tried playing with the path but nothing works. Not sure what I might be missing here? Any thoughts, thanks

Comment: No Idea, try other solutions to load sctipt

Comment: I guess in the path you do not need to mention "public", just /assets/js/... should do when referring it inside meteor